# How to resolve "Input string was not in a correct format." error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**What I tried:**

**MarkUP:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TextBox2"  Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    <asp:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1"  TargetControlID="TextBox2"  BoundControlID="Label1" Maximum="200" Minimum="100" runat="server">
    </asp:SliderExtender>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void setImageWidth()
{
    int imageWidth;
    if (Label1.Text != null)
    {
        imageWidth = 1 * Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);
        Image1.Width = imageWidth;
    }
}
```

After running the page on a browser, I get the `System.FormatException`: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Change `Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text)` to `Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)`

Comment: @AndreCalil I just tried and still got the same error

Comment: At `SliderExtender1`, change `Bound` and `Target` controls

Comment: why should I ? isn't it the problem with the C# code ?

Comment: Why do you have a label and a textbox?

Comment: What are you using for your Slider? Telerik, AjaxControlToolKit, something else? Find out where your result should be read from. The exception is telling you that the contents of Label1.Text can't be converted into an Int32.

Comment: @Kevin I am using AjaxControlToolkit and my result should come from Label1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is with line

```
imageWidth = 1 * Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);
```

`Label1.Text` may or may not be int. [Check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx%20for%20exceptions).

Use `Int32.TryParse(value, out number)` instead. That will solve your problem.

```
int imageWidth;
if(Int32.TryParse(Label1.Text, out imageWidth))
{
    Image1.Width= imageWidth;
}
```

Comment: This error message could be thrown when try to Convert.ToDouble input comming from user with different cultureinfo, so you could use Convert.ToDouble (String, IFormatProvider) instead of just Convert.ToDouble (String). It is hard to debug, because program will work on you system, but will throw error on some of its users, this is why I have a method to log errors on my server and I found out for the problem fastly.

Answer (score 3):

If using `TextBox2.Text` as the source for a numeric value, it must first be checked to see if a value exists, and then converted to integer.

If the text box is blank when `Convert.ToInt32` is called, you will receive the `System.FormatException`. Suggest trying:

```
protected void SetImageWidth()
{
   try{
      Image1.Width = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
   }
   catch(System.FormatException)
   {
      Image1.Width = 100; // or other default value as appropriate in context.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Label1.Text` is holding `Label` which can't be parsed into integer, you need to convert the associated textbox's text to integer

```
imageWidth = 1 * Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
```

Comment: I just tried and still got the same error

Comment: put a break point and see what is inside TextBox2.Text

Answer (score 0):

Replace with

```
imageWidth = 1 * Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);
```