# ASp.net WebForms C# Convert String To Int32 All ways are not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to convert a string value to int32 and I tried all the solutions on the web also my own solutions and nothing is working???

I'm reading x,y,width and height from Cropper.js Plugin using asp.net C# and I have a value like this:19.999999999999999

how on earth could I convert it to integer
I tried :

```
 (int)Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Decimal.Parse(W.Value.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US"))));
```

and all variations also
int.parse, int32.parse and tryParse

nothing is working, please note that i'm saving the values in Asp:Hidden field and read it on server side nothing is working please help!!!!

```
 <script>
    function CallCropper() {
        var image = document.querySelector('#image');
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#image').attr("src", $("#ImagePathHidden").val());
        }, 1);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                autoCrop: true,
                crop: function (e) {
                    $("#X").val(e.detail.x.toString());
                    $("#Y").val(e.detail.y.toString());
                    $("#W").val(e.detail.width.toString());
                    $("#H").val(e.detail.height.toString());
                    //alert(e.detail.x.toString().replace(/\,/g, '.'));
                },
                movable: false,
                zoomable: false,
                rotatable: false,
                scalable: false
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

ASpCode:

```
 protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string ImageName = Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();

    decimal MyW = Decimal.Parse(W.Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    int Myw2 = (int)Math.Round(MyW);

    int w = Myw2;
    int h = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Decimal.Parse(H.Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
    int x = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Decimal.Parse(X.Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
    int y = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Decimal.Parse(Y.Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));

    byte[] CropImage = Crop(path + ImageName, w, h, x, y);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length))
    {
        ms.Write(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length);
        using (SD.Image CroppedImage = SD.Image.FromStream(ms, true))
        {
            string SaveTo = path + "crop" + ImageName;
            CroppedImage.Save(SaveTo, CroppedImage.RawFormat);
            ImageSrc = "upload/crop" + ImageName;
            ImagePathHidden.Value = ImageSrc;
        }
    }
}

static byte[] Crop(string Img, int Width, int Height, int X, int Y)
{
    try
    {
        using (SD.Image OriginalImage = SD.Image.FromFile(Img))
        {
            using (SD.Bitmap bmp = new SD.Bitmap(Width, Height))
            {
                bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution, OriginalImage.VerticalResolution);
                using (SD.Graphics Graphic = SD.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), X, Y, Width, Height, SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    bmp.Save(ms, OriginalImage.RawFormat);
                    return ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw (Ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Did you verify if the value is present before trying to parse?

Comment: Yes it gives string format error i read a solution about converting comma to dot and i used regx but also not working

Comment: Also i changed the croping functionality from on load to on button click same error i tried to alert the value and it is valid but server side code crash on runtime

Comment: What is the datatype of W.Value? And what is your locale?

Comment: I looked for the documentation and i found that the value of hidden field is string

Comment: Try to use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture instead of a specific culture.

Comment: And the parameters of croping method is int32 for x,y, width & height

Comment: Same error for currentculture

Comment: Also (im trying to think loud) if the number is bigger than int32 i did round it but it is same error . What is happening?????

Comment: I suggest you to split that long line in its parts using temporary variables and then use the debugger to see step by step what values are assigned to the variables and which function throws the exception for the input received

Comment: Also i tried substring to cut the long number but it is still format error

Comment: Ok steve i will do that and see please stay with me it is critical from me thanks in advance

Comment: I edited my question the value of the hidden filed is "" can you find what I'm missing

Comment: I am sorry but I am not an expert of javascript. It seems that your _e.detail.width_ is blank but I cannot tell you why,

Comment: Try to remove SetInterval and SetTimeout. Where is the call to CallCropper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer this question which I asked the answer is all the ways is working that I mention but the reason why would it not convert is because the value was null, so if anyone face the same problem and tried all the ways mentioned on stack overflow or the internet and it wont work the reason is the value is null, this is what happened in my case I spent hours and hours on trying online solutions and after @Steve said to trace carefully the values I found that I pass null to the string.

Answer (score 0):

a little test with text from a label (using 19.999999999999999):

```
decimal num;
if(decimal.TryParse(lblNumberToConvert.Text, out num))
{
    lblConvertNumberResult.Text = num.ToString();
}
```

see: [how to resolve "Input string was not in a correct format." error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269254/how-to-resolve-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-error)